# How to display foreign key objects in admin page?

Tags: python, django

For background, this is my first Django app.

The basis of this assignment revolves around exploring a database.  There are Areas, and within these areas are Locations.  These locations reference what area they belong to via  foreign key.  I need to display all locations belonging to an area when on that area's "change" page.  This(https://i.postimg.cc/mhfmG21C/assign07-one-area-listing.png) is what it is supposed to look like.

Here is my code and what it currently looks like.  I know there are methods for accessing objects related via foreign key (ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey), but I don't know how to use them.

```
    class AreaInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Location
    extra = 1

class AreaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #fieldsets = [(None,{'fields': ['id','name','latitude','longitude']}),
     #            ('Locations', {'fields': ['id','name']})]
    inlines = [AreaInLine]
```

This(https://i.postimg.cc/sxZT8Zx3/Capture.png) Is what it currently looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch `StackedInline` with `TabularInline`. Try this:

```
class AreaInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Location
    extra = 1
```

Comment: That just makes it into a table.  It's still the same thing.https://i.postimg.cc/4xQnVfZd/Capture.png

Comment: It looks like the screenshot you shared saying "supposed to look like this". What is the problem? If you expect some inline objects to be shown, they will appear once new related objects are added. If the problem is about these relations, you should share your models' code, too.

Comment: I need it to display locations rather than give me boxes to add new ones.

Comment: As I said, you should share your models, too.